# VBA delete ASCII chars

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a VBA sub, that checks a up to 4 digit number and deletes ASCII 0-32 chars.

This is what the numbers look like:
[image: This is what the numbers look like]

Im a student, which is why I need this for an asignment, but I have been stuck here for the last hour with no progress, and TRIM seems to do nothing.

Comment: Fun little assignment. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. Input values along with expected output and most importantly *your own attempt*.

Comment: `Trim` only removes spaces but not the other ASCII chars that you mentioned. Actually ASCII below 32 are control codes and usually not displayed. Are you sure you have ASCII 0-31 in your cells? Can you show what exactly you have tried with `trim`? Where is that data? In multiple cells or in one cell?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub C_Click()
    For Each Cell In Worksheets("C").Range("A1:A10")
        For i = 0 To 32
            Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, ChrW(i), "")
        Next i
    Next Cell
End Sub
```